# System of linear equations with four unkowns

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have no idea how to solve this system of equation :
$$\begin{align}u+v+w&=7 
\\v+w+x&=-8 
\\w+x+u&=5 
\\x+u+v&=-10\end{align}$$

I usually use the addition/substraction method, but it leads no where in this case...

A little hint would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

To use the addition/subtraction method as you call it, you often need to add/subtract more than just two of the equations together when there are more than two variables and equations involved. Here, because of the symmetry, we can do something much easier and more concrete. Add all four of the equations together to get $3u+3v+3w+3x = -6$, giving

$$ u + v + w + x = -2$$

Subtract from this equation each given equation, and in turn you will get the answer for each variable. Subtracting the first given equation, for example, from the above equation you get $x=-9$, and so on.

Comment: nice idea(+1). i almost wrote the same.

Comment: Ok, the only thing which I don't understand is when you talk about symmetry... Other than that I understand the rest of what you said.

Comment: Also, I was wondering, I know that I need to reduce 4 equations of 4 unknowns to 3 equations of 3 unknowns. But in this case, it doesn't seem to lead anywhere when I get those 3 equations... Is it possible or not ? (I do prefer your method, way easier.)

Comment: When I talk about symmetry, I am just utilizing the similarity in the equations given in the problem; I saw that each equation was missing one of the variables from it, each equation missing a different variable. I general, it is difficult to solve equations in four or more variables with this addition/subtraction method, because you would have to figure out just the right combination of equations to add together to cancel a variable, which is just as hard as solving the original system. A more reliable option is solving one equation for a certain variable, and substituting that in the others.